# Create script database using smo and c#.How do you do it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I need to create a database on a local server and only if not exists.
How do you do it using sqlsmo?

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a SQL Database Programmatically](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CreateSQLDV.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't seem to take into account dependencies.